# Angular set pristine doesn't work as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am trying to create a custom validation on one of my inputs. Everything works as expected but the error css class is still applied. I tried with `$setPristine()`
and `$setUntouched()` first on the input (didn't work) and then on the form. The perfect solution will be if I can reset the style in ng-change.

```js
self.changeTransferNumber = function () {   
  if (validateRoutingNumber(self.bankTransferNumber)) {
    self.bankInfoForm.bankTransferNumber.$error.validateTransferNumber = false;
    self.bankInfoForm.$setPristine();
    self.bankInfoForm.$setUntouched();
  } else {
    self.bankInfoForm.bankTransferNumber.$error.validateTransferNumber = true;
  }
}
```

```html
    <form name="$ctrl.bankInfoForm" novalidate ng-submit="$ctrl.saveInfo($event)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.bankTransferNumber" ng-disabled="$ctrl.disableTextEdit" name="bankTransferNumber" required ng-change ="$ctrl.changeTransferNumber()"/>
    <div ng-messages="$ctrl.bankInfoForm.bankTransferNumber.$error" ng-show="$ctrl.bankInfoForm.bankTransferNumber.$dirty">                                                   
     <div ng-message = "validateTransferNumber" >The transfer number is not correct</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: could you provide also the full html form

Comment: Do you think of writing a validation directive instead of using these? Just an offer

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your Form name in html:-

```
 <form role="form"  name="Form" id="Form" ng-submit="Form.$valid && saveFormData($event,Form)" novalidate  autocomplete="off">
```

in Your controller /js file :-

```
 $scope.saveFormData = function (event,myForm) {
           //after your whole logic
           ....
           //to reset form
           myForm.$setPristine();
 }
```

What i understand from this question....

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to reset the css style in ng-change

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a custom validator using a directive? This way it's easily reusable.

```js
(function() {
 'use strict';
  
  angular.module('myApp', []);
  
  angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', MyController);
  
  MyController.$inject = [];
  function MyController() {
   var main = this;
    
    main.routingNumber = '2';
  }
  
  angular.module('myApp').directive('validateRoutingNumber', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
      require: {ngModel: ''},
      bindToController: true,
      controllerAs: '$dir',
      controller: function() {
       var $dir = this;
        
        $dir.$onInit = function() {
          createValidators();
        };
        
        function createValidators() {
          $dir.ngModel.$validators.routingNumber = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
            var value = modelValue || viewValue;
            //without this if-else it would become a required field
            if (value) {
             return value.toString().length >= 3 && value.toString().indexOf('1') !== -1; 
            } else {
             return true; 
            }
            
          }
        }
        
      }
    };
  });
  
}());
```

```css
input.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px red solid;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as main">
    <form name="frmMain">
      <input type="text" ng-model="main.routingNumber" name="routingNumber" validate-routing-number>
      <span ng-if="frmMain.routingNumber.$invalid">Needs to have at least three characters and at least one '1'</span>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```